# MouseEnter Event Handler for RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, mouseevent

I'd like to add a MouseEnter event handler to my RichTextBox which I have in a tabcontrol. The following code gets the currently selected RichTextBox:

```
 private RichTextBox GetRichTextBox()
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = null;
        TabPage tp = tabControl1.SelectedTab;

        if (tp != null)
        {
            rtb = tp.Controls[0] as RichTextBox;
        }

        return rtb;
    }
```

The next code is what I use to create the new tab with the RichTextBox:

```
TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Document");
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        tp.Controls.Add(rtb);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
```

I am not sure how to go about creating the Mouse Enter Event Handler for the RichTextBox that is created. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same place that you create the RichTextBox, you can add an event handler to any event you want. simply do something like this:

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
// the rest of your code...
rtb.MouseEnter += rtb_MouseEnter;

void rtb_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do what ever you want here...
}
```

Comment: Oh geez, I feel stupid. I had tried something similar to this but I guess I had went wrong somewhere. Thank you. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mouse listener, add mouse listeners to the object that needs them.

```
    ....
    TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Document");
    RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
    rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    //Add listener
    rtb.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Control1_MouseClick);

    tp.Controls.Add(rtb);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);    
    ...
}

private void Control1_MouseClick(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    //Stuff
}
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'OnMouseEnter' event of the RichTextBox class. Just register for the event when creating the RichTextBox object:

```
TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Document");
    RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
    rtb.MouseEnter += MyHandler;
    rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    tp.Controls.Add(rtb);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
```

And then put your code you want to execute in your eventhandler:

```
private void MyHandler(object s, EventArgs e)
{
   // code to be executed on mouse enter
}
```

Also you should deregister your event at an appropriate point.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler to your RichTextBox before adding it to your tab control

```
rtb.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(TabControlMouseEnterEvent);
```

Then create the event handler

```
    private void TabControlMouseEnterEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RichTextBox rt = (RichTextBox)sender;
        // do something with selected Rich Text Box

    }
```

Hope this helps.